# Jquery UI file inclusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I just downloaded the pack for jquery UI, and when I extract it I get these files:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/NOutnsR.jpg]

My question is that what files should I include? There're a lot of files there I'm not sure which one I'll need to put into my folders for full functionality. I know for sure I need to include jquery-ui.js or jquery-ui.min.js but I also want the themes that come with it and use them on my webpage. SHould I include the css and files inside external and images too?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need the minified css and js files.

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/